# Alternative to Get-Content

Tags: powershell, out-of-memory

I currently have the following line of code.

```
(Get-Content 'file.txt') |
  ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''} |
  Set-Content 'file.txt'
```

This worked when testing, but now I am trying to use it on real data files (13 GB) and this process of using Get-Content is causing Powershell to consume a large amount of RAM and ultimately all of the available RAM on the machine.

Is there a better way that I can achieve the same result without the same amount of overhead?

Seems I am doing the opposite of best practice but not sure what else would be cleaner/ less RAM intensive than the above.

Comment: The title wouldn't make it obvious unless you already knew the method for solving this problem, but it is a duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192072/how-to-process-a-file-in-powershell-line-by-line-as-a-stream

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to process a file in PowerShell line-by-line as a stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192072/how-to-process-a-file-in-powershell-line-by-line-as-a-stream)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a stream to read the file, then it won't put it all into memory, you can also use a stream to write the output. This should perform pretty well, and keep memory usage down:

```
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg "c:\test\file.txt"
$outstream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "c:\test\out.txt"

while ($line = $file.ReadLine()) {
  $s = $line -replace '"', ''
  $outstream.WriteLine($s)
}
$file.close()
$outstream.close()
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you chose different methods for creating reader and writer?

Comment: Using the Stream Reader method appears to do the trick. Very fast and the memory usage didn't go over 1% once.

Comment: I tried testing this against a 1GB .etx log file, and for some reason it quit about 3MB into the file.

Comment: Just figured out that if it hits a null line, it quits there.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechars, no reason, just illustrating different syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem isn't caused by `Get-Content`, but by the fact that you're running the statement in an expression (i.e. in parentheses). Running `Get-Content` like that is a convenient way of allowing a pipeline to write data back to the same file. However, the downside of this approach is that the entire file is read into memory before the data is passed into the pipeline (otherwise the file would still be open for reading when `Set-Content` tries to write data back to it).

For processing large files you *must* remove the parentheses and write the output to a temporary file that you rename afterwards.

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\file.txt' |
  ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''} |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\temp.txt'

Remove-Item 'C:\path\to\file.txt'
Rename-Item 'C:\path\to\temp.txt' 'file.txt'
```

Doing this avoids the memory exhaustion you observed. The processing can be sped up further by increasing the read count as [@mjolinor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32337077/1630171) suggested (cut execution time down to approximately 40% in my tests).

For even better performance use the approach with a `StreamReader` and a `StreamWriter` that [@campbell.rw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32337282/1630171) suggested:

```
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader 'C:\path\to\file.txt'
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter 'C:\path\to\temp.txt'

while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
  $line = $reader.ReadLine().Replace('"', '')
  $writer.WriteLine($line)
}

$reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
$writer.Close(); $writer.Dispose()

Remove-Item 'C:\path\to\file.txt'
Rename-Item 'C:\path\to\temp.txt' 'file.txt'
```

Comment: The .peek() method for testing whether your at EOF doesn't have the problem of ending the loop if it hits a null line.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as the accepted one does not take into account blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster than line-by-line processing, and still keep your memory consumption under control:

```
Get-content 'file.txt' -ReadCount 5000 |
 foreach-object {$_ -replace '"', '' | 
 add-content 'newfile.txt' }
```

Comment: Hi mjolinor, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it set to 5000 to begin with and a few other times with the Readcount set lower but powershell crashed each time. Get-content doesn't appear suited to the situation.

Comment: I've used this many times to read large files with good results.  Define "crashed".

Comment: The memory usage kept rising (albeit slower than what I initially had) and eventually powershell became unresponsive and closed down.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I closed the foreach block too early.  See if it works better now.